# how to order the color dropdown data when in click will move to the part that I put it using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to order the color dropdown data when in click will move to the part that I put it using jquery ??

[image]

```
<div class="row-cont mb-10 controls">
                <div>Product Color</div>
                <ul class="select5-container variant-color selected-color">

                </ul>
                <div class="select5__option-container color-select-holder">
                  <ul class="row-cont select5__option span12 color-select" id="ssss">
                    <li class="span6">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="" value="White">
                      <label class="mb-0">
                        <a>
                          <span class="colorpick-dot" style="background-color:#ffffff;"></span>
                          White
                        </a>
                      </label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="span6">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="" value="Black">
                      <label class="mb-0">
                        <a>
                          <span class="colorpick-dot" style="background-color:#ffffff;"></span>
                          Black
                        </a>
                      </label>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
```

//JQUERY

```
$("#ssss").on('click','li',function (){
  alert($(this).find("input").val());
});
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. You want to select the radio button(say black) then the highlighted dropdown will populate the value "Black". Please confirm.

Comment: yes it is more or less like that :(

Comment: Yep, not clear. @Eksa, could you edit your question to explain the wanted behaviour?

Comment: I've found what I want, but how to make what I have selected or click it can not be selected again ??

Comment: $("#ssss").on('click','li',function (){
      var datas = $(this).find("input").val();
      $("#ss").append('<li class="selected span6"><div class="colorpick-dot-holder"><span class="colorpick-dot" style="background-color:#ffffff;"></span></div><div class="variant-name">'+ datas +'</div><div class="tag-close"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></div></li>');
    });

Comment: Add some id in your dynamic `li` And check if that `id` is not exist then only add

Answer (score 0):

> how to make what I have selected or click it can not be selected again ?

You want the `li` to be clickable only once?

Look for the `unclicked` class in the code below.

```js
$("#ssss").on('click','li.unclicked', function(){
  alert($(this).find("input").val());
  $(this).removeClass("unclicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row-cont mb-10 controls">
  <div>Product Color</div>
  <ul class="select5-container variant-color selected-color">

  </ul>
  <div class="select5__option-container color-select-holder">
    <ul class="row-cont select5__option span12 color-select" id="ssss">
      <li class="span6 unclicked">
        <input type="checkbox" name="" value="White">
        <label class="mb-0">
          <a>
            <span class="colorpick-dot" style="background-color:#ffffff;"></span>
            White
          </a>
        </label>
      </li>
      <li class="span6 unclicked">
        <input type="checkbox" name="" value="Black">
        <label class="mb-0">
          <a>
            <span class="colorpick-dot" style="background-color:#ffffff;"></span>
            Black
          </a>
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```